# R markdown knitr using the LaTeX environment minted when rendering to PDF

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am using the fabulous `knitr()` package in R to render rmarkdown to PDF via LaTeX. Since the default syntax highlighting is not what I want, and the LaTeX environment `listings` has severe limitations in highlighting R code, I wanted to use the LaTeX `minted` package, simply embedding the knitted code into the minted environment.

Did anybody make it work to use the LaTeX package `minted` with knitr?

I already am failing loading the minted package with a weird error :D

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "me"
date: "10. March 2019"
output: 
  pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{minted}
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
minted_hook = function(x, options) { paste0("\\begin{minted}{R}", x, "\\end{minted}\n") }
knit_hooks$set(
  source = minted_hook,
  warning = minted_hook,
  message = minted_hook,
  error = minted_hook
)
```

# Test
```{r}
# this is a comment
a <- 1:10
a
```
````

As soon as I load minted I get the error

```
"C:/PROGRA~1/PANDOC~1.1/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.tex --template "[path not shown]\R\WIN-LI~1\3.5\RMARKD~1\rmd\latex\DEFAUL~3.TEX" --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" --variable "compact-title:yes" 
tlmgr search --file --global "/(.sty"
Fehler in grep(paste0("/", x[j], "$"), l) 
> invalid regular expression '/(.sty$', Reason 'Missing ')
```

I did install pygminted as outlined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23458/how-to-install-syntax-highlight-package-minted-on-windows-7/55249).

Comment: It should read `\usepackage{minted}` with curly braces. But there seem to be further problems after that change.

Comment: yupp that twas a typo, I of course used curlys, the issue is real.

Comment: The error message (which I cannot reproduce using pandoc 2) does make sense in conjunction with that typo. If you get that error even when using curly braces, then please try to reduce the resulting tex-file as far as possible and post the result.